# elisp: Why does + without parameters return 0?

Tags: numbers, elisp-conventions

In elisp `+` function without parameters gives 0, `(+) ==> 0`. `*` function without parameters give 1: `(*) ==> 1`. Only `(/)` gives error: `wrong number of arguments`.

But in Python entering `+` without summands give an error: `+ ==> SytntaxError: incomplete input`.

I was wondering what were the justifications for this behavior in elisp.

[elisp arithmetic operators](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Arithmetic-Operations.html)

Definition of `+`

> (+ &rest NUMBERS-OR-MARKERS)
>
> Return sum of any number of arguments, which are numbers or markers.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: The closest equivalent of the elisp `+` function in Python is the Python `sum` function, not the Python `+` operator. If you ask Python to add nothing by typing `sum([])`, it will do exactly the same thing that the elisp `+` function does: it will return 0.

Comment: As @TannerSwett (in the above comment) and @shynur (in a comment below his answer) have said, you should think of `+` as a `sum` function, not as  a binary operator. The mathematical convention (and it is just a convention, although a very useful one) is that an empty sum has the value 0 and `+` follows that convention. The reason it is useful is that it allows you to prove things without having to deal with the case of the empty list separately from the case of the non-empty list: it makes proofs shorter and easier. Similarly for `*` and `product`.

Comment: IMHO this is a Lisp question, not just elisp, as @Drew has already noted. If I encountered a Lisp that didn't behave this way, I'd wonder what else was broken.

Comment: The brief answer is that `+` acts as  a monoid homomorphism. I don't know how to cleanly express that in Lisp, but in Python, it just means that since integers under addition with identity 0 form one monoid and lists with concatenation and identity `[]` form another, then `sum(a + b) == sum(a) + sum(b)` for any two integer lists `a` and `b`. Since `a == a + []`, then `sum([]) == 0` so that `sum(a) == sum(a) + sum([])`.

Answer (score 10):

Math. The sum of nothing is obviously nothing. The product of nothing is more mysterious, because it *isn’t* nothing. But if you look closely you will soon notice that in both cases you get back the identity element for the operation. The identity element for addition and subtraction is zero, because adding or subtracting zero gives you back whatever you started with. The identity element for multiplication (and division) is one, because multiplying or dividing by one gives you back whatever you started with.

Why do the identity elements matter, you ask? Consider the following sums:

| elisp | simplifies to |
| --- | --- |
| `(+ x x x x)` | = 4x |
| `(+ x x x)` | = 3x |
| `(+ x x)` | = 2x |
| `(+ x)` | = 1x |
| `(+)` | = 0x |

As you can see, the sum of an empty list really is zero. This is a restatement of the [proof offered on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_sum), which you might take a look at if you want references. A similar proof works for products:

| elisp | simplifies to |
| --- | --- |
| `(* x x x x)` | = x⁴ |
| `(* x x x)` | = x³ |
| `(* x x)` | = x² |
| `(* x)` | = x¹ |
| `(*)` | = x⁰ |

Anything raised to the zeroth power is one, so the product of an empty list is also one. It’s the only number that makes sense there. Again there is a [proof on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_product), with additional information relevant to set theory and category theory, along with references.

---

In response to your comment that you still don’t see why `+` doesn’t complain about missing arguments, look again at the declaration:

```lisp
(+ &rest NUMBERS-OR-MARKERS)
```

You can see that it is defined to take no required arguments, and to put all additional arguments into a list called `NUMBERS-OR-MARKERS`. So you can see right away that it will not give you an error if you don’t pass in any arguments.

Comment: Interesting. I didn't realize `(-)` was zero in Elisp. `(+)` and `(*)` make sense to me, but having the non-commutative one accept no arguments is kind of strange, especially since `(- x)` is a fundamentally different operation than `(- x y)`. Common Lisp rejects `(-)`, so it's interesting that Elisp chose to diverge from its inspiration on this.

Comment: Silvio: Elisp was based on MacLisp: http://www.maclisp.info/pitmanual/number.html#9.12 (there is also a deviation from that in elisp (or at least in modern elisp), but it's regarding no-argument and single-argument division, rather than subtraction).

Comment: "*The sum of nothing is obviously nothing*": But `0` is not "nothing".

Comment: Of course it is.

Comment: @U.Windl I agree that `0` is not nothing, at least for lisp. `(+ nothing nothing)` gives “unbound variable” error. `(+ “nothing” “nothing”)`gives type error: “nothing” is not a number.

Comment: We have now descended into sophistry...

Comment: @SilvioMayolo `-` is just `+` with right hand operator multiplied by `-1`. If you imagine `(-)` as [left fold function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)) with initial value being identity element being the same as for addition — zero, and with list, obviously, empty — it makes sense. `0 + (-<no value>) = 0 + <no value> = 0`.

Comment: I think what you added in the middle of your answer is just what I already mentioned in my answer. Repeated the exact same thing.

Comment: Yes, deliberately so. The goal is to get the best possible answer, so I added an explanation akin to yours and the one that @U.Windl found on Wikipedia, as well as the links to the articles he mentioned. I hope that by formatting the explanation as I did the pattern is as intuitive as possible.

Comment: @db48x: "*The goal is to get the best possible answer*" -- Then I think you also need to explain some concepts about ELisp. **All the answers assume that OP has some basic knowledge about ELisp**, so they focus on explaining mathematical concepts, but from the comment (*I agree that `0` is not nothing, at least for lisp. `(+ nothing nothing)` gives “unbound variable” error. `(+ “nothing” “nothing”)` gives type error: “nothing” is not a number.*) from OP, it *seems* that …

Comment: I agree that @zeynel’s comment indicates a lack of understanding of how lisp works, I think he should ask a separate question about that confusion rather than try to explain the whole language here.

Comment: x^0 being 1 is a matter of definition, and only commonly defined to be 1 for convenience (as 0^x is less important than x^0).

Comment: If you want to suggest a footnote, please do. However since 99% of people never use the type of mathematics where an alternate definition of x⁰ would be useful, I suggest that maybe it is not actually necessary to mention it.

Comment: How does `(+)` in your last row know to say "`0x`". I don't see any `x`s in `(+)`.

Comment: Because it literally has zero x’s in it, while the line before had one and the line before that had two. Of course it also has zero y’s too, so you could say that it equals 0y. That still equals zero though because anything times zero is zero.

Answer (score 9):

This is a very **natural** outcome.

For instance,

```
(+ 2 10 30)
```

you know the result is `42`, right?  
So, what if we remove the `10`?  
Obviously, the result will decrease by `10`, meaning the result of

```
(+ 2 30)
```

is `32`.  
Then what if we remove the `2` from the above expression?  
Exactly, the result of

```
(+ 30)
```

will decrease by `2`.  I.e., the result is `30`.  
And we finally remove the `30`; obviously the result of

```
(+)
```

is `30 - 30 = 0`.

The same logic can be applied to `*`.  
(Even to the factorial, which is that exclamation mark `!`.  This is why `0! = 1`.)

Comment: and why `x^0 = 1`, etc. Mathematical intuition.

Comment: "what if we remove the 40..." I am not sure. If we remove one of the parameters + function should complain that an argument is missing. (like in Python). So in elisp, it seems, this convention was implicitly added to +. I don't see it in the formal definition of +. (I added that to the question.)

Comment: @zeynel The plus sign here actually represents the sum (sigma)

Comment: Actually I think `+` with less than two arguments should be `nil`.

Comment: That would make programming a lot harder: you would have to check for `nil` in a gazillion places and go different ways depending on the answer. You still have to worry about the type of the arguments with `+` but you don't have to make sure that the list of numbers you apply it to is non-empty.

Comment: This is a much better answer than the "sum of nothing is obviously nothing" one.

Comment: I have a problem with your answer. There is no arithmetic operation called "remove". I notice that your first two operations are "remove" but your last operation is "substract". That's not fair:) You don't do `(+ 2 30 (- 10))` but you "remove" 10 from the list. But at the last step you subtract, `(- 30 30)` to get `0`. Tell me if I am misunderstanding you. Otherwise good answer.

Comment: @zeynel Of course there is no "remove" mathematical operator. "Remove" refers to **writing one less digit** than you did in the previous equation; based on my answer, you will find that for every digit you omit, the result of the expression will be less by that omitted digit, which is easy to understand, right?

Answer (score 6):

This is due to associativity of addition:

```
Sum(Array1) + Sum(Array2) = Sum(concat(Array1, Array2))
```

If Array1 is [empty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_set), we get

```
Sum(Empty) + Sum(Array2) = Sum(Array2)
```

thus `Sum(Empty)=0`.

See also https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/9422#issuecomment-343548481

The python error is due to deficiencies of syntax, not any math.
Even in python `sum([])` is 0.

Comment: This also explains why `(*)` returns `1`, and Common Lisp `(every #'predicate '()` returns `T`.

Comment: I agree with the recursive definition, but *why isn't it required that `+` has at least two arguments?* Adding an infinite series of "Sum(Empty) +" to a sum doesn't really help.

Comment: @U.Windl: why should we put an arbitrary limitation on `#'+`?

Answer (score 4):

I think you ask *both*:

1. Why are `+` and `*` multiple-arity functions and they allow even zero arguments?
2. Why isn't this the case for `/` (division)?

Others have answered #1: both `+` and `*` have an [**identity element**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_element):
0 for `+` and 1 for `*`.
0 + *N* = *N*, and *1* * *N* = *N*, for any number *N*.

The answer for #2 is that `/` (division) has *no* identity element. There's no number *N* such that for **any** number *M*, *N*/*M* = *M*.

Answer (score 2):

I found [Empty sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_sum) and [Empty product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_product).

So `+` and `*` do not follow the typical *binary operator rules*, but the mathematical definitions of sum and product.

Basically it's what [db48x's answer](/a/79828/22153) said already.

Comment: Good job thinking of looking for proofs on Wikipedia; that didn’t occur to me.

Comment: There are no proofs, simply because these are conventions: useful conventions and therefore universally adopted in math textbooks - but they are conventions nevertheless.

Answer (score 2):

Although everyone has been addressing the correctness of the sum of zero values being zero, no one seems to have really taken up the Python aspect of this.

The "syntax" for (e-)lisp `+` is just like that of any other function call `(func args...)`, i.e. it is a list where the first element is the function to call, and the remainder of the list is the argument(s) to pass. The only oddity is that the name of the function is made up of special characters rather than alphanumeric ones. As such then, the arguments can have any count including zero.

The restriction you see in Python is a syntactic one: The `+` operator is binary and requires two operands (actually, I'm not sure if unary prefix `+` exists). This restriction forbids having no arguments, but equally forbids having more than two. You can add several values using several-1 `+` operations which is just iteratively applying the binary addition operator, but there is no syntax that uses a single `+` and more than two operands. As some have mentioned, the closest thing is the `sum` function, which follows the same behaviour (in this aspect, anyway) as the `+` function in (e-)lisp.

Answer (score 0):

As far as `elisp` is concerned this is what I understood from answers and comments:

`(+ 3)` and `(+)` are hardcoded into `+` function's source code to give `(+ 3) ==> 3` and `(+) ==> 0` to conform to mathematical conventions. The rest is the subject of mathematics. So, there is nothing else to discuss as far as `elisp` is concerned.